# In autoit hotkey setting, how can I set the hotkey "ctrl + shift + alt + F1" to work?

Tags: autoit, shift, alt, ctrl

I tried defining it as seen below, but it is not working.

```
HotKeySet("^+{ALT}{F1}", "function")
```

How can I make a hotkey composed of more than 4 keys with Ctrl, Shift and Alt keys?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) for <kbd>ALT</kbd> is `!`:

```
HotKeySet("^+!{F1}", "function")

While True
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

Func function()
    ConsoleWrite("Hotkey triggered" & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>function
```